# Is it logic to perform a time to event analysis (survival) when the event will always occurr?

Tags: regression, survival, biostatistics

My question is regarding a hypothesis of a medication X that decreases viral shedding. I know that even for the placebo patients viral shedding will occur but of course later. Is it logic to perform a time to event analysis or in this case is preferable to do a simple linear regression?

Comment: I think it makes sense. Will all subjects experience the event (viral shredding) within the observation window?

Comment: Yes, all the patients will experience the event in the time of follow-up

Comment: You'll be fine to apply time-to-event analysis. If all subjects experience the event, it just means that you'd expect all your survival probabilities to go to 0.